# ProgressDialog not showing up in activity

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am trying to include a ProgressDialog in my application. But it is not showing up.

Here's the code snippet where i use the ProgressDialog:

```
public class abcActivity extends Activity {
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        case XYZ:
            ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(abcActivity.this, "", "Please wait for few seconds...", true);
            callSomeFunction();
            dialog.dismiss();
            showToast(getString(R.string.SomeString));
            break;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the dialog is not showing up? Any clues?

Comment: Maybe it's not getting into that case statement? Try adding a `Log.v("onOptionsItemSelected", "in XYZ");` - see if it's even going there.

Comment: xil3 is right, it could not be entering `XYZ`.
Or maybe callSomeFunction() is executing to fast?

Comment: The logs in callSomeFunction() are printed. This means that the switch case is hit.

Comment: Check how long the callSomeFunction() lasts. It could be too fast for you to see the ProgressDialog.

Comment: callSomeFunction() calls another function which in turn executes a native method. Sometimes it lasts as much as 6 seconds. Still the ProgressDialog is not seen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your code is wrong in a sense that you do all in the UI thread. You have to put callsomefunction() into a background thread.

```
public void runSomething()
{
    showDialog(BACKGROUND_ID);
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {                   
        public void run() 
        {
            //do something
            handler.post(finishThread);
        }
    });

    t.start();
    // The progress wheel will only show up once all code coming here has been executed
}
```

And as well

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    if(progressDialog == null) progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    return progressDialog;
}

@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog)
{
    if(id == BACKGROUND_ID) 
    {
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("running for long ...");
    }
}

Runnable finishThread = new Runnable()
{       
    public void run() 
    {
//long running
        if(progressDialog != null) progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes true. When I moved the ProgressDialog to a new thread, it started to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not ProgressDialog. It's any UI component. You're in the UI thread, so you cannot update other UI components while you are using the thread to do something else. Either spawning another thread to update the UI, or spawning another thread to perform your work are acceptable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have this code called by debugging or adding a log. The code seems right to me.

Also, if you want to perform some operations in background and show a progress dialog while the performing, please use AsyncTask with ProgressDialog bounded, like [here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).

Comment: That's a good point, but that's not the problem he's asking about.

Comment: +1 It's not his exact point, but @Vladimir Ivanov provided a **better** way of performing a long running task.  In fact, since `callSomeFunction()` is running on the UI thread, could it be blocking the creation of the dialog?

Comment: Vladimir: The link provided by you is broken. Kindly re-check.

Answer (score 0):

i think issue is in your switch condition pls verify it.

here is another method to display dialog in android try this.

```
public static final int DIALOG2_KEY = 1;
public static ProgressDialog dialog1;

showDialog(DIALOG2_KEY); // use it where you want to display dialog 

dialog1.cancel();  // use it to cancel the dialog


@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        if (id == 1) {
            dialog1 = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog1.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog1.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog1.setCancelable(true);
        }
        return dialog1;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't really help answer the question - we've established that he knows how to use ProgressDialog, and the way he's done it is correct. Actually, the way he has it is way neater than what you've just done. The problem lies elsewhere. And why do you have a method that returns Dialog if you've made dialog1 a public property? Doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: @xil3 `onCreateDialog(int id)` is an overridden method on the [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int%29) class, it **has** to return `Dialog`.

Answer (score 0):

ProgressDialog is deprecated in Android O , Use ProgressBar now.